IFrame Connector cannot be deployed
I'm getting this error in CiviCRM admin alerts:
IFrame Connector: Deployment
The IFrame Connector cannot be deployed. The template class ("Civi\Iframe\EntryPoint\WordPress") is missing.

This is a new civicrm installation and I can't figure what is missing or how to solve this issue. Could you help me please?
Thanks!
